# Can I improve my logistic regression model by feature selection, or something else?

Tags: logistic, modeling, feature-selection

I started working on a logistic regression model using R and below is the summary of the model.

```r
> summary(log_model1)

Call:
glm(formula = Outcome ~ ., family = "binomial", data = train_data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.4397  -0.7175  -0.4329   0.7320   2.9974  

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              -7.819019   0.859810  -9.094  < 2e-16 ***
Pregnancies               0.154985   0.043442   3.568  0.00036 ***
Glucose                   0.036756   0.004881   7.530 5.09e-14 ***
BloodPressure            -0.011813   0.006859  -1.722  0.08503 .  
SkinThickness             0.002365   0.008933   0.265  0.79118    
Insulin                  -0.002169   0.001165  -1.862  0.06261 .  
BMI                       0.078997   0.018930   4.173 3.00e-05 ***
DiabetesPedigreeFunction  1.063802   0.379849   2.801  0.00510 ** 
Age                      -0.004717   0.013132  -0.359  0.71947    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 591.85  on 459  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 432.41  on 451  degrees of freedom
AIC: 450.41

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I tested the accuracy on both the train and test dataset but it was not that great (80 for train, 70 for test data). Is there any way the accuracy of model can be improved?  Would it help to:

1. Add extra features? (If yes, on what basis features need to be selected?)
2. Removing the existing features? (If yes, on what basis features need to be rejected?)
3. Standardize the dataset?

Correct me if I am wrong in any of the above points.

Comment: How did you compute the accuracy for a logistic regression model?  Logistic regression only gives you predicted probabilities, not hard class assignments.  You should not be evaluating the performance of a logistic regression (or arguably any model) on the basis of classifcation accuracy.

Comment: How do you know the underlying relationship makes a better model possible? Maybe this is as good as it gets.

Comment: How did you compute the accuracy for a logistic regression model? -- I used an ifelse statement to predict 1,0 based on the cut off I got from ROC curve. Then I came up with confusion matrix to calculate the accuracy.

Comment: How do you know the underlying relationship makes a better model possible? -- Maybe adding extra features would fit in better way if the classifications/data is not linearly separable .. Please correct me if I am wrong ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest OP to think about the [Bayes Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_error_rate) first.

> I have tested the accuracy on both Train and test dataset but it was not that great (80 for train, 70 for test data).

Why do you think the accuracy is not great? What is the "threshold" to be considered as great performance? Note that, for some data, getting 70% accuracy would be awesome. Say online advertising prediction, can we have some model that 70% of the time, the the user will buy the product we recommended? For other applications 95% accuracy can be bad, for example, MNIST [handwritten digit recognition problem](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

---

My answers to the questions

1) Adding extra features ?

In general, adding features could be helpful, but have the risk of over fitting.

2) Removing the existing features ?

If you discover you are overfitting, removing features could be helpful

3) Standardizig the dataset ?

Not helping if you are using logistic regression without regularization.

BTW, hope I am not rude and my answer is helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. Now I got some more clear picture on this. Is there any other ways to increase the accuracy for this model (except the adding extra features). 70% would be great but still if I have to achieve 90%.